# Anyone does compare two csv files in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Does anyone did this thing before using c# apps? I have two csv files and I need to compare this two csv files and log those missing data from CSV1 to CSV2.

Scenario :

1. Compare two CSV files
2. If some data does not exist in CSV1 from CSV2 then create a report and list down those data that does not exist from CSV1 to CSV2.

I need your help for this one guys. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have to use C#? There are many good programs already written, such as WinMerge.

Comment: Hi Eugene, yes I need to do this using c# to automate. I've 200 csv file that needs to compare. I tried to explore the WinMerge and it seems it's not applicable for my requirements. Though it quite helpful but the problem is in WinMerge their we manually do the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your data into a datatable. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F) is a nice example of a CsvReader that imports your data.

And here is an [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386998.aspx) that shows the intersection of two datatables. If you change it to use Except instead of Intersect you will get the difference.